# Odd Divisor Numbers in a Range not starting at 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can we find, given a range of numbers, how many of those numbers have odd divisors? After some searching, I noticed that perfect squares have this nature only. However, this is only if you start from $1$. What if you wanted to find the total number of numbers that have odd divisors in a range not starting at $1$? For example, in the range $[16,25]$ there are $2$.

Comment: I think you mean "odd **number of** divisors".

Comment: In any case, the answer is within your question. Suppose you know how to compute the number of perfect squares in the range $[1,n]$. Let's call your computation utility $f(n)$. Then in order to to compute the number of perfect squares in the range $[a,b]$, simply calculate $f(b)-f(a-1)$. In your example: $f(25)-f(16-1)=5-3=2$.

Comment: What is a "number with odd divisors" and which ones are in the range $[16,25]$?

Comment: @barakmanos Yes that's what I meant

Comment: Do you understand my following comment?

Comment: By the way, in case you don't already have it figured out, $f(n)=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$.

Comment: @barakmanos Yes thank you. Is this the only way, or is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: @user340314: Shorter than $\lfloor\sqrt{25}\rfloor-\lfloor\sqrt{16-1}\rfloor$???